# Snapshot in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Hello I am new to VirtualBox. I installed Mac in my Windows XP, I did my project in that, now my system got crashed. I have no other option but formatting my system, but before that I would like to copy my VirtualBox image which I worked via Linux.

Could you please tell me where I can find my snapshot image, so that I can mount my image on my newly formated Windows VirtualBox?

Answer (score 1):

In your user folder (I think it is `C:\Documents and Settings\yourusername` in Windows XP) you will find a folder `.VirtualBox` where VirtualBox stores configuration files and virtual hard drives by default.

The configuration files keep all your settings. You can open those on the new host machine and they will configure the machine automatically. But usually need a similar host otherwhise you will have many errors.

Though I think what your looking for are the virtual drives. You can just copy those and then when creating a new virtual machine select them instead of creating a new one.

Comment: To expound on @MSIS's comment: 1) As MSIS said, that location is the default one.  If you changed it, you should look in your configured location.  2) Yes, you should only need the virtual hard drive image. Configure the new VM with the same options and specify your recovered disk image.  It should boot normally.